EfficientNetB4 with cuda python
I would like to build model EfficientNetB4() with use of GPU.
I have already configured CUDA on my machine:

However I cannot build a model since I every time have an message:

that EfficientNetB4() has no attribute to. I would be grateful for help.
Different way of activating calculation on "cuda" but it didn't work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Copy-and-paste the actual text into the question instead and format it using code blocks.
